# Prove the integral form (Gamma Function)

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

How do you show that
$e^y = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{y^n} {n!}~dy$? 
and yet, my textbook yields the following equation from that one, 
$n! = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} y^ne^{-y}~dy$

Here is my attempt:
$\displaystyle n!~\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{0}^{a} y^n~dy \\ = n!~\lim_{a \to \infty \left[\dfrac{1}{n+1} y^{n+1}\right]_0^a \\ = \dfrac{n!} {n+1} \lim_{a \to \infty} a^{n+1}$
What is the next step?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

It is correct that
$n! = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} y^ne^{-y} dy
$.

You can not take the $e^{-y}$
out of the integral.
In general,
you can not take
any function of
the variable of integration
($y$ in this case)
out of the integral.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. By the way, how do you prove the value of that integral?

Comment: Start with $n=0$, then use integration by parts to go from $n$ to $n+1$. Ask Euler.